# Zero Centering Audio for Forward FFT

Tags: fft, ifft

I'm trying to work out the best way to zero centre an audio clip for a forward FFT.   I've been trying rotate my audio so that a peak exists mid way (N/2).   This seam a little naive and I thought I had read that you can zero pad the centre of the audio clip in order to achieve the same result.  Am I mad?  what is the best way to zero centre an audio clip for Forward FFT

Comment: Eureka!    You can get a zero centered waveform of an audio clip by applying a window, i used hann (cosine) window and then inverting the left and right sides.    I guess my question then becomes Do you need to ensure a peak at N/2 prior?

Comment: your comment should be an answer. Don't worry, answering your own question is encouraged!

Comment: LOL.  Its probably the only question I'll ever answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! You can get a zero centered waveform of an audio clip by applying a window, i used hann (cosine) window and then inverting the left and right sides.